# How to add elements to an existing Bokeh chart

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to do a simple real-time stock data visualizer using Bokeh. I have created the object data type `Candle` which has the attributes `time`, `highest`, `lowest`, `open` and `close`. `candle1`, `candle2`, and `candle3` are instances of `Candle`. I use the following piece of code to show a graph with the data of those 3 instances. If I want to add a 4th candle after I have shown the chart (after calling show(plot)), how should I do it? I think that I do not achieve it because because the html contains static data, but I do not have any clue about how to do what I want.

The objective would be to receive a candle per minute and add that to the chart.

```
plot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", width = 1000, height= 300, title ="Live Chart", sizing_mode  ='scale_both')
plot.segment(candle1.time, candle1.highest, candle1.time, candle1.lowest, color="black")
plot.segment(candle2.time, candle2.highest, candle2.time, candle2.lowest, color="black")

plot.vbar(candle1.time, 0.5 *60*60*1000, candle1.open, candle1.close,fill_color="#00ff80", line_color="black")
plot.vbar(candle2.time, 0.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000, candle2.open, candle2.close, fill_color="#00ff80",
          line_color="black")
output_file("candlestick.html", title="Candle example")
show(plot)
```

Comment: you want to use the bokeh serve option from your command line.  More info on how to format your code here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/selection_histogram.py

Comment: Just an update: I have achieved this using a ColumnDataSource, the stream function and an automatic callback.

Comment: you can add your solution as an answer to your own question so that others know what to do in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update: I have achieved this using a ColumnDataSource, the stream function and an automatic callback.

```
def update():
     candle_data.stream(new_data, 300)   

plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',x_range=(start_day, final_day), width=1500, height=900, title='Live Chart', sizing_mode='scale_both')
    plot.segment(x0='time', y0='highest', x1='time', y1='lowest', color='black', source=candle_data)
    plot.vbar(x='time', width = 0.5*60*60*50 ,bottom='open', top='close',fill_color='color', line_color='black', source = candle_data) doc.add_root(column([plot]))
doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 20000)
doc.title = "Candle Data Live Rates"
```